# Rx swift - Date picker freezes Rx swift View controller

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Here is code i am using, i am new to rxswift. My question is simple when i tap on textfield date picker opens and it freezes my ViewController. I don't know what is the problem with UI in rxswift, this works well in only swift project. Your help is appreaciated pls help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     //Text Field Connection
   @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
   //Uidate picker
   let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   //show date picker
     showDatePicker()
  }


   func showDatePicker(){
   //Formate Date
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

    //ToolBar
   let toolbar = UIToolbar();
   toolbar.sizeToFit()

   //done button & cancel button
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "donedatePicker")
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
   let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "cancelDatePicker")
   toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

// add toolbar to textField
txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
 // add datepicker to textField
txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker

   }

 func donedatePicker(){
  //For date formate
   let formatter = DateFormatter()
   formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
   txtDatePicker.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
   //dismiss date picker dialog
   self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

      func cancelDatePicker(){
       //cancel button dismiss datepicker dialog
        self.view.endEditing(true)
      }
   }
a
```

Comment: Give us more details about freezing? Do you need restart a Xcode or stopping an app is sufficient?

Comment: In the code snippet, there is no RX code. Give us more details about the Rx

Comment: @Adobels- yes i need to restart app

Comment: Hi. I pasted your code into Xcode 11.3, got rid of all the warnings, and tested it. Your code works once you clear the warnings.